# Passing 'dict' object from Django Template to Angular Controller - avoid jsonify and parsing

Tags: python, json, angularjs, django

I'm trying to call an angular controller function from my django template, and pass the object I'm iterating upon, but it requires me to first convert the object to json before passing, and then in controller, I've to again parse the json to object.

Here's the snippet:

**Django TemplateView:**

```
class Menu(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'menu.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Menu, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Using the DRF API to fetch the data for template view
        menus = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/menus/').json()
        context['menu'] = menus
        return context
```

**menu.html:**

```html
<div class="row" ng-controller="MenuController as vm">
    <ul>
        {% for menu_item in menu.menu_items %}
            <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <!-- menu_item is dict type object -->
                <button class="btnRed txtUpper" 
                    ng-click="vm.addToCart('{{ menu_item|to_json|escapejs }}')">
                    Add to cart
                </button>
            </li>
         {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

`to_json` is my custom filter:

```
@register.filter
def to_json(value):
    return json.dumps(value)
```

Now, in my controller, to use the passed object, I've to again parse the json to object:

```
angular.module('menu', [])

.controller('MenuController', ['$log', function($log) {
    this.addToCart = function(menuItem) {
        menuItem = JSON.parse(menuItem);
        $log.debug('Adding MenuItem to Cart: ' + menuItem);
        $log.debug('Adding MenuItem to Cart: ' + menuItem['id']);
    };
}]);
```

So, there are multiple stuffs I've to do there. For one time it's fine, but it would be to much if I've to do this for every template and angular integration. Is there any elegant way to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

You seem quite confused about how a JS frontend and a REST backend should work. There is no need for your TemplateView here. Your JS should be making the request directly to the DRF endpoint, which will return JSON directly.

Comment: Yeah that can be done. But I'm writing TemplateView here for some purpose. So, I need that. Basically it's a multi-page app, instead of conventional single-page app.

Comment: Well, I don't really understand what you mean, but you certainly shouldn't be doing a requests call to the API from within your view. Do it from Angular.

Comment: Ok, earlier I was using DRF directly from angular. That's why I'd created those APIs. But now what I want is to have separate pages for separate menu Item, for the crawler to follow. With angular single-page app, that won't be possible. That is why we moved to TemplateView.